# How to extract a word from denormalized text?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, text

I want to extract a word or group of words from a field in the table.

E.g I have a table named `flight_passenger` which contains a field named `passenger_address` .
The `passenger_address` has data such as  **12/1 , ring road , bangalore-20** . Now, I want to get the city name (bangalore here).

All other records in this field follow same format.

Comment: If you're using MySQL you're not using "ANSI SQL", and can use any of the [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) that MySQL provides.

Comment: Well , I searched a lot .. but didn't find the exact method.

Comment: [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: @Bill Karwin : The `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will return `bangalore-20`, as it can take only one separator , `,` here. But, I want only `bangalore`.

Comment: @user2190060, so use SUBSTRING_INDEX() again on the result, with a separator of '-'.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this for SQL Server 2012

```
 select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE('12/1 , ring road , bangalore-20'),0,CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE('12/1 , ring road , bangalore-20'))))
```

it returns :  bangalore-20